# I am trying to pass data from my controller to a plugin. But i need to first pass it to a view which then calls the functions in the plugin

Tags: pyrocms

Here is my controller

```
public function ajax_filter() {
    $filters = array(
                      'start_date'=>    $this->input->post('start_date'),
                      'end_date'  =>    $this->input->post('end_date'),
                      'project'   =>    $this->input->post('project'),
                      'repo'      =>    $this->input->post('repo'),
                      'coder'     =>    $this->input->post('coder'),
                      'user_id'   =>    $this->current_user->id
                );

    // $start_date = $this->input->post('start_date');

    $view = $this->load->view('overview', $filters, TRUE);

    $ret = array(  'view'  =>  $view);

    die(json_encode($ret));
}
```

`$view = $this->load->view('overview', $filters, TRUE);`
i think the problem may be with this line, any other ways to pass the data to the view?

Comment: what is your goal? why do you want to pass it to plugin

Comment: I have changed that line of code to be  
    $view = $this->template
      ->set_layout(null)
      ->build('overview', $filters, TRUE);

Comment: Now my view loads when i check it on the console. But in the view 'overview' I try to vardump $filters and it says its undefined. I have tried these variations to output it in my view.     <p><?php echo $filters['start_date'];?></p>
    <p> {{ filters['start_date']}} </p>

Comment: and 'overview' calls my plugin functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass it to a plugin. Just sayin.

Also, if you pass the $filters array directly, $start_date will be available in the view but there is no access to $filters itself.

```
$view = $this->load->view('overview', compact('filters'), TRUE);
```

That'll make $filters work in that view.